# How to get current foldername and remove characters from the name in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, makefile

I'm trying to write a single command in my makefile to get the current folder and remove all "." from the name.
I can get the current folder with `$${PWD##*/}` and I can remove the "."s with `$${PWD//.}` but I can't figure out how to combine these two into one.

The reason I need this is to kill my docker containers based on name of project. This is my command:

```
docker ps -q --filter name="mycontainer" | xargs -r docker stop
```

and i was hoping I could inject the project name before my container name like this:

```
docker ps -q --filter name=$${PWD##*/}"_mycontainer" | xargs -r docker stop
```

Comment: Not possible.  Assign in between: `q=${PWD##*/}; echo ${q//.}`.

Comment: @Alfe of course is possible...

Comment: @ingroxd Then show me a way to combine the two operators (`${v##*/}` and `${v//.}`) in one term.

Comment: @Alfe The question is `How to get current foldername and remove characters from the name in bash`: I don't see any `with parameter expansions`... The OP is asking `"[...]a single command[...]"`, and you can achieve it in different ways. We are here to help each other and not to demonstrate how capable we are, so if you have anything that can improve the answer or the question, feel free to help us out. If you don't, we will appreciate the silence.

Comment: @ingroxd Wow, that was impolite.  I referred to the sentence »I can't figure out how to combine these two into one« when I said that isn't possible.  I was just giving a comment, not a perfected answer.  And I even provided a working workaround, using both proposed means (without directly combining them, as that is not possible).  I'd appreciate when being misunderstood to be given the benefit of the doubt instead of a rude response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
var=$(echo ${PWD##*/} | sed "s/\.//")
```

or:

```
var=$(tmp=${PWD##*/} && printf "${tmp//./}")
```

In your use case will be something like:

```
docker ps -q --filter name=$(tmp=${PWD##*/} && printf "%s_mycontainer" "${tmp//./}") | xargs -r docker stop
```

Note that there are more ways to do that (even more efficient).

Comment: I had to use `tr` since I'm running this in a Makefile: `docker ps -q --filter name=$$(printf '%s_container' "$${PWD##*/}" | tr -d .) | xargs docker stop`